# Possible combinations for this example

Tags: combinatorics

I'm currently writing about databases and superkeys and I need a little help with the following issue.

For one element:

```
Elements: A
Combinations: A
```

For two elements:

```
Elements: A, B
Combinations: A, B, AB
```

For three elements:

```
Elements: A, B, C
Combinations: A, B, C, AB, AC, BC, ABC
```

I would like to know how many possible combinations there are for `n` elements following the scheme I described above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In effect you have a sequence $\langle a_1,\ldots,a_n\rangle$ (i.e., your ordered set of elements), and you want to know how many non-empty subsequences it has. You get a non-empty subsequence by picking any non-empty subset of the elements. A set of $n$ elements has $2^n$ subsets, but one of those is empty, so there are $2^n-1$ non-empty subsequences.

Comment: @xxsl: You’re very welcome.

Comment: Another way to look at it: n choose 1 + n choose 2 + ... + n choose n